# Question RE Using React Class Fields with Async/Await on Arrow Functions

Tags: reactjs, async-await

When using React's Class Fields syntax, how can I use async/await and try/catch on arrow functions for my "events" (markComplete, addTodo)?

Would it better to just use a constructor and bind the custom methods in there than using class fields and arrow functions?

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    todos: [],
  };

  // async/await here, I understand
  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(
        'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?_limit=10'
      );
      const data = await res.data;
      this.setState({
        todos: data,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }

  // Q: how can I use async/await and try/catch here?
  markComplete = id => {
    this.setState({
      todos: this.state.todos.map(todo => {
        if (todo.id === id) {
          todo.completed = !todo.completed;
        }
        return todo;
      }),
    });
  };

  // Q: how can I use async await and try/catch here?
  addTodo = title => {
    axios
      .post('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos', {
        title,
        completed: false,
      })
      .then(res =>
        this.setState({
          todos: [...this.state.todos, res.data],
        })
      );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>...</Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the arrow function async as well.

```
addTodo = async title => {
  try {
    await axios.post('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos', { title, completed: false, })
    .then(res => this.setState({ todos: [...this.state.todos, res.data] }));
  } catch(err) {
    // Handle err
  }
};
```

What you have with the returned promise from axios is fine, you can add a catch block to the promise chain.

```
addTodo = async title => {
  await axios.post(
    'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos',
    { title, completed: false, }
  )
  .then(res => this.setState({ todos: [...this.state.todos, res.data] }))
  .catch(err => {
    // Handle err
  });
};
```